# MVC ASP.NET Sometimes Request is not made to the server

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project in MVC5 for over 3 months. I have implemented Login and Registration features and used Ajax calls to get the response from the server. A few days back I have met with an issue that sometimes when making request for login or registration the system gets frozen and no response is received, but the next time If I try to do the same the server responds as intended.

We have different Environments on which we test the application, Running the application locally never revealed the issue but when deployed on our quality server the issue is causing trouble when user logs in or registers.

I have also included Logging on server side but for requests for which server doesn't respond there is no logging information available which means that the request has not been actually made to the server.

I am posting my code below ,kindly give me solution that how can I get rid of this problem. Because it doesn't generate an error or exception so there is nothing I can assume about the issue that what is actually wrong with it. Why it works? and why sometimes it doesn't?

**Login client side**

```
$.ajax({

                url: "@Url.Content("~/Account/Login")",
                method: "POST",
                data: AddAntiForgeryToken(form + "&returnUrl=@ViewBag.ReturnUrl"),
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response.result == "Redirect") {
                       // setTimeout($.unblockUI, 1000);
                        //   $('#loginHeader1,#loginHeader2').hide();
                        //   $('#logoutHeader1,#logoutHeader2').show();
                        $('.loginMsg').text('Redirecting...');
                        if (response.url == "@Url.Content("~/Home")" || response.url == "")
                            window.location = "@Url.Content("~/Home")";
                        else
                            window.location = response.url;

                    } else if (response.result == "Error") {
                        // $.blockUI.defaults.message = "<h2>Username of password is not valid..</h2>";
                        $('.loginMsg').text('Invalid username or password.');


                        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 1000);
                        $(".leftCol,.rightCol").addClass("errorMsg");
                    }

                }
            });
```

**Login Server Side**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        _logginService.Error("Inside Login Method");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _logginService.Error("(Login)Model state invalid , returning view");
            return View(model);
        }
        _logginService.Error("(Login) Model state valid");
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        _logginService.Error("(Login) checking user credentials");
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            _logginService.Error("(Login) user exists, creating identity");
            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            string roles = string.Empty;
            _logginService.Error("(Login) getting roles for user");
            var objUserRoles = user.UserRoles;
            _logginService.Error("(Login) checking if role is null");
            if (objUserRoles != null)
            {
                _logginService.Error("(Login) objUserRoles is not null");
                foreach (var userRole in objUserRoles)
                {
                    _logginService.Error("(Login) inside foreach loop");
                    roles += userRole.Role.Name + ",";
                }
                _logginService.Error("(Login) trimming roles");
                roles = roles.Trim(',');
                _logginService.Error("(Login) adding identity claims");
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roles));
            }
            _logginService.Error("(Login) signing in identity user");
            AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);

            //MandrillWrapper mailer = new MandrillWrapper("PdVD3kQ4dIIqJs0teQtHgw");
            //var res = mailer.SendPurchaseRequest("112df2", "itec.sania@gmail.com", "sania.awan@seventechnology.co.uk", "ORCHA Report", @"D:\Studies\Books\LINQ query examples using method and query syntax.pdf");
            _logginService.Error("(Login) returning json response");
            return Json(new { result = "Redirect", url = returnUrl });
        }
        else
        {
            _logginService.Error("(Login) returning json response with error");
            return Json(new { result = "Error" });
        }

    }
```

**Registration Client Side**

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Register", "Account")',
                    data: AddAntiForgeryToken(form + "&Gender=" + gender + "&YearOfBirth=" + year),
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {

                        if (response.success == "true") {

                            $('.RegMsg').html('Registeration successfull, Please wait...');
                           // setTimeout($.unblockUI, 1000);
                            window.location = response.url;

                        } else if (response.success == "false") {

                            var errors = response.error.split(",");
                            var errorText = "";

                            $.each(errors, function (index, value) {
                                if (value.toString().indexOf('Name') > -1) {
                                    value = value.toString().replace('Name', 'Email');
                                }
                                errorText += value + "<br>";
                            });

                            $('.RegMsg').html(errorText);
                            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 3000);

                        }
                    }
                });
```

**Register Server Side**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterDeveloper(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        var PasswordHasher = new PasswordHasher();
        try
        {
            if (model.Email != null && model.Password != null)
            {
                var user = _userRepository.Get(x => x.Email == model.Email);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    user.PasswordHash = PasswordHasher.HashPassword(model.Password);
                    user.IsActive = true;


                    var invitation = _invitationRepository.Get(x => x.Email == model.Email && x.IsExpire == false);
                    if (invitation != null)
                    {
                        invitation.IsExpire = true;
                        _invitationRepository.Update(invitation);
                    }

                    _userRepository.Update(user);

                    return await this.Login(new LoginViewModel
                    {
                        Email = user.Email,
                        Password = model.Password
                    },null);
                }
                return Json(new { success = "false", message = "No user exists with the given email" });
            }
            return Json(new { success = "false", message = "Invalid email or password" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = "false", message = ex.Message });

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can better use Ajax.beginform to avoid these kind of issues

Comment: Ajax calls are easily made with ajax.beginform

Answer (score 0):

how about you try $.post(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
instead of $.ajax call